# CakePHP check user role

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I check if the currently logged in user belongs to the admin role.

I have two tables, a users and roles table. In the users table I have a foreign key called `role_id`. And a role of admin is ID of 1 in the roles table.

1.) How would I do this check in the view to show an admin link

2.) How would I do this check in the app_controller to prevent access to all actions that have the admin prefix?

I have tried something like:

```
public function beforeRender()
{
    $user = $this->Auth->user();

    if (!empty($user))
    {
        $user = $user[$this->Auth->getModel()->alias];
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));


    if($user['Role']['id'] == 1)
    {
        $is_admin = true;
    }
}
```

and then I try and use the `is_admin` variable to check around the app

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way of doing this is setting a variable in your controller functions

```
   function beforeFilter()
    {
    if($this->Auth->user('role_id')==1){
    $this->set("role",$this->Auth->user('role_id'));//it will set a variable role for your view 
     }
else
{
$this->set("role",2);//2 is the role of normal users

}

    }
```

in your view you test this variable like below

```
    <?php if($role==1){ ?>
      echo $html->link('view registered users',array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'admin_check_users'),array('title'=>'Users'));/provide a link for admin using html helper;   }
    else{
     echo $html->link('logout',array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'logout'),array('title'=>'Logout...'));//provide a link for normal users using html helper;   

}
?>
```

for your 2nd answer... you can do the same...

```
      function beforeFilter()
    {
    if($this->Auth->user('role_id')==1){
     $this->Auth->allow('admin_view','admin_controls');//put your all admin actions separated by comma

     }


    }
```